# Where can I obtain the wurfl_patch.xml file

Tags: php, wurfl

I'm busy implementing the wurfl api using PHP, but somehow just can't seem to find where I need to download the wurfl_patch.xml file. [Patch file](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/patchfile.php)

Does anybody have the file stored somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you don't *need* a patch file.

A patch file is used so that your changes is kept in one place, and the library can update normally without breaking your changes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I think you have to write the patch yourself.

Comment: that's probably the reason I can't find it :-)